# How do I add text and two count statements to google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to get google sheets to say (21/44) with checkboxes so I have

=COUNTIF(C3:C46, TRUE) and =COUNTIF(C3:C46, FALSE)

but I want both in the same cell, separated by a "/"

Answer (score 1):

add `& "/" &` between the formulas and it will work :)

```
=COUNTIF(C3:C46, TRUE) & "/" & COUNTIF(C3:C46, FALSE)
```

[image]